# Windows 8.1 Backup System Image on Samba Share - 0x807800C5 - 0x80070001 (Invalid Function)

Tags: linux, windows-8.1, samba, windows-server-2012-r2

This was the error message of the backup utility:

**There was a failure in preparing the backup image of one of the volumes in the backup set. (0X807800C5)

Additional Information: Invalid Function (0x80070001)"**

I was trying to backup my windows 8.1 to a linux based (Ubuntu 14.04) Samba share (Samba version 4.1.6).

Comment: It is perfectly fine to answer your own question, but please separate them. Answer goes below, you can accept it after a certain time IIRC.

Comment: Thanks for that hint, I hadn't thought of this while typing.

Answer (score 0):

The main cause was this:
Virtual hard disk cannot be created on an SMB server without resiliency support from a Windows computer (see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2920193/en-us)

To solve this, you have to install this update:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2919355/de

The update above will be installed automatically, if you have manually installed this prerequisite update: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2919442/en-us

**So, in short terms I installed [KB2919442](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2919442/en-us), rebooted the computer, searched again for windows updates and now KB2919355 was in the list of available update and I installed that one, too.**